# como flotar dos tabla con HTML2PDF

Tags: php, html, pdf, table, html2pdf

Estoy generando un pdf mediante HTML2PDF, pero al estructurar el pdf me doy cuenta que mis tablas no se acoplan al diseño que realice al pasarlo en la hoja de pdf...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

estas se visualizan una debajo de la otra y necesito que estén una al lado de la otra, estoy usando float:left; y float:right para esto y en el navegador no hay problema pero al pasarlo a pdf se ponen una debajo de la otra

```
<table border="1" align="left" class="tablaReportG" style="float:left; margin-top: 10px; width:200px;">

<table border="1" align="right" class="tablaReportG" style="float:right; margin-top: 10px; width:200px;">
```

Comment: Prueba dandole **float: left** a las dos; Si utilizas left y right cada tabla estará en cada extremo de la hoja, es decir, estarán separadas. debes darle la misma propiedad a las dos

Comment: esa prueba la hice y el problema no es ese, como se muestra en la imagen cada tabla ocupa una fila completa aunque yo le asigne un espacio determinado.. mi intención es que las dos tablas estén en la misma fila una al lado de la otra

Answer (score 0):

Listo ya encontré una solución a lo que quería hacer, a continuacion una imagen de referencia:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El proceso que realice fue el siguiente: la tabla 2 la puse de primero en el código y la tuve que poner dentro de otra tabla (que llamare tabla mayor) como se muestra a continuación.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y luego colocar la estructura de la tabla 1 debajo de la tabla 2 pero fuera de la tabla mayor
**NOTO: si encuentran otra forma me comentan**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias por responder, tu colaboración es bienvenida. Sin embargo, te invito a leer [answer] y a realizar el [tour] para que conozcas un poco más el funcionamiento de Stack Overflow. Es muy importante que agregues todo el código como texto y no como imágenes. Saludos